# Debugging Qt app with Qt Creator: <no such value>

Tags: debugging, ubuntu-12.04, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator with Qt 5.1.1 in Ubuntu 12.04.
When I'm using the debugger to show content of any variable, the window always show "no such value" on every variable. Also on variables of type `QString`, `int` etc.
Is there a configuration problem on my Ubuntu?
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is there some text or code missing? Why is the headline different from the question text?

Comment: i changed the description

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you start a new sample project in Qt Creator? Could you provide any code that shows where the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes, the problem also exists on new projects. I wrote a simple main with a QString inside and the debugger show only "no such value" as content.

Comment: I have same problem.  Ever find a fix?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a year and a half ago, but the problem still remains actual for Ubuntu 12.04, Qt Creator 3.4.0 based on Qt 5.4.1.

As mentioned in [Qt Creator Manual](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html)

> Starting with version 3.1, Qt Creator requires the Python scripting extension. GDB builds without Python scripting are not supported anymore and will not work. The minimal supported version is **GDB 7.5** using Python version 2.7, or 3.3, or newer.

I suppose that `gdb --version` gives you 7.4 (the last version of gdb for Ubuntu 12.04). That's why you have *no such value* issue.

### 1. Install a fresh gdb (7.8)

Remove the current gdb (to avoid conflicts with new one) and install development packet for python ([to build gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968286/1104612) with Python scripting)

```
sudo apt-get remove gdb
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

Install gdb from the [sources](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/)

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.8.tar.xz
tar -xf gdb-7.8.tar.xz     
cd gdb-7.8/     
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-python
make
sudo make install
```

Now **gdb 7.8** is in `/usr/local`.

### 2. Update Qt Creator settings

- Open menu `Tools` > `Options ...`
- Select `Build&Run`, tab `Debuggers`
- Click **Add**
- Type **Name** you like, write **Path:** `/usr/local/bin/gdb`
- In tab `Kits` change **Debugger:** with that you just created

Hope this help someone who still love Ubuntu 12.04 and Qt.

Comment: This solved my issue, when I type gdb --version on terminal it was showing error like python module load failed. Then I proceed the above steps  and works fine, I have used the `--prefix=/usr` instead `--prefix=/usr/local` while configuring, so the Qt creator easily find the debugger without additional setting change.

Comment: additionally to the above instructions, I had to install termcap libraries: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` but everything else worked, so thx!