# Cannot debug in Qt Creator - no such value

Tags: linux, qt, gdb

I'm using QtCreator 6.0.2, in ubuntu 22.04.01.

When I try to debug, whenever I hover over a variable I cannot read the actual value. Instead I see <no such value>.

I read this question: [Debugging Qt app with Qt Creator: <no such value>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517764/debugging-qt-app-with-qt-creator-no-such-value) which offers some insight. But I think the answer is too old. I have not recompiled gdb, but when I run gdb --configure I can see that it was build with python scripting support:

> This GDB was configured as follows:    configure 
> --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
> --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
> --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
> --with-expat
> --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/share/gdb (relocatable)
> --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/lib/gdb (relocatable)
> --without-libunwind-ia64
> --with-lzma
> --with-babeltrace
> --with-intel-pt
> --with-mpfr
> --with-xxhash
> --with-python=/usr (relocatable)
> --with-python-libdir=/usr/lib (relocatable)
> --with-debuginfod
> --without-guile
> --enable-source-highlight
> --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/lib/debug (relocatable)
> --with-system-gdbinit=/etc/gdb/gdbinit
> --with-system-gdbinit-dir=/etc/gdb/gdbinit.d

what else could cause this? where could I get more info how to fix this? logs? where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to build a FULL_DEBUG build like this (I'm using cmake):

```
cmake ../trunk -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=FULL_DEBUG
```